# Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.Type'

Tags: sql, powershell

I have a PowerShell script trying to run a sql command using **Invoke-Sqlcmd** but I get the following exception:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd : The pipeline has been stopped.
At D:\Scripts\powersehelscript.ps1:57 char:9
+ $rows = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT * from TableName where location is  null;"  ...
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], PipelineStoppedException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlExectionError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptComman
 Invoke-Sqlcmd : Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type
'System.Type'.
At D:\Scripts\MyScript.ps1:57 char:9
+ $rows = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT * from TableName where location is null;"  ...
```

my sql command looks like this:

```
$rows = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT * from TableName where location is null;" -Database $Database -ServerInstance $SqlServer -Username $U -Password $P
```

It seems to be connecting fine to the Database and if I run the same query directly in the DB i get the results back.

From the exception I see **"Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type"** but I have no clue why this casting issue is occurring

Comment: What happens when you don't try to assign the output to a variable?  What happens if you change your query to `"SELECT 1 from TableName where location is null;"`?

Comment: if I don't assign the output to the variable I still get the same error, if I do Select 1 I get column 1 and 111111......

Comment: If I do "where location is not null" then no exception is thrown, do I need to cast this to a nullable type?

Comment: Huh.  Well, my guess was that your query is having trouble retrieving metadata from the database.  In other words, it can't resolve `*` to column names.  If that were the case, I'd try specifying your column names, or possibly grant VIEW DEFINITION to the login (not necessary if the login is in the sysadmin role).  However, I'm no longer sure if changing the WHERE clause like that resolves the error.  I guess I'd try to see if it's related to a specific column, specific column order, or specific record.

Comment: You were right its related to an specific column, the column Location its of type geography so by doing a select on all the columns except this one it worked

Comment: Interesting.  I wonder if Invoke-SqlCmd doesn't support geography or geometry data types then?  You might have to use SqlClient directly like you were running C# then if you need that.  Or it might simply be that the DbGeography type isn't available.  Try `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Data.Entity` or `Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"`, and then try the full query.  The geography should map to System.Data.Spatial.DbGeography type.

Comment: @BaconBits I know this is a old thread but if you post your comments above as answer will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone reading this is looking for other conclusions, I had exact same issue of PowerShell same error and it grinding down to a single geo column.  I was simply writing some code to grab the table and export once a week for easy user reference. The Add-Type solution didn't change my outcome.  What worked for me was, in the SQL cmd, using CAST(mygeocol AS varchar(100)).  Conveniently, in SQL & PS, that brought it back to a format like "POINT (-90.1234 30.1234)" and worked great.  Hope it helps someone!